# Suppress Meta Log In, Log out from pages when the theme has no reference to it

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a theme (ward) that has no reference to the Meta / Site Admin / Log Out but I am still seeing it at the bottom of every page/post. I have looked all php files from the theme and I cannot see any mention to that.

How do I get rid of this? Is there any hook to get rid of this?

[image]

---

edit

This is my Meta on the appearance widgets:

[image]

But as you can see I have nothing on the first sidebar or home page

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is, in `sidebar.php`:

```
<?php
/**
 * The first/left sidebar widgetized area.
 *
 * If no active widgets in sidebar, alert with default login
 * widget will appear.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
?>
<div id="secondary" <?php bavotasan_sidebar_class(); ?> role="complementary">
    <?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar' ) ) : ?>

    <?php if ( current_user_can( 'edit_theme_options' ) ) { ?>
        <div class="alert alert-warning"><?php printf( __( 'Add your own widgets by going to the %sWidgets admin page%s.', 'ward' ), '<a href="' . admin_url( 'widgets.php' ) . '">', '</a>' ); ?></div>
    <?php } ?>

    <aside id="meta" class="widget">
        <h3 class="widget-title"><?php _e( 'Meta', 'ward' ); ?></h3>
        <ul>
            <?php wp_register(); ?>
            <li><?php wp_loginout(); ?></li>
            <?php wp_meta(); ?>
        </ul>
    </aside>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div><!-- #secondary.widget-area -->
```

It's the `wp_loginout()` that's causing it.

Comment: unfortunately there is no such thing on my sidebar and the meta thing is not appearing on the sidebar but on the front page. If you want to check, I am using the WARD theme.

Comment: I did check your theme, that's where I found it ;)

Comment: Unfortunately I have removed that line and the problem still shows but like I said, the meta stuff appears just on the front page... and no, front-page.php, index.php or page.php have no `wp_loginout()`. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I installed ward theme and there is a meta widget on widget screen (Appearance > Widgets). Remove that, and it should be gone. Really nothing else there that should do that...

Comment: thanks. I have added more info to the question to show you I have nothing there. Try this: 1. create a page  2. make this page the front page. Visit that page. Is the meta visible at the bottom?

Comment: Yup it's visible, because I have Meta on my First Sidebar: http://i.imgur.com/G3mPfJ8.png?2 Once I go to widgets and remove it it's gone.

Comment: I don't even have a sidebar

Comment: Then either you have different theme (https://bs.wordpress.org/themes/ward/) or you've modified it heavily...